# How to set checkbox so :checked is accurately evaluated

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have the following html/css which hides a checkbox and displays a left/right toggle in it's place.  When it's checked the following css kicks in.

```js
document.getElementById("partner-1").checked = false;
$("#partner-1").prop("checked", false);
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 17px;
  top: 2px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
  transform: translateX(13px);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 17px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.switch.large {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
}

.switch.large .slider:before {
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
}

.switch.large input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50px);
  transform: translateX(50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="switch large">
  <input type="checkbox" id="partner-1">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

I have validation in place where if the user doesn't provide enough information when submitting a form, it unchecks the checkbox.  In that case, I'm expecting the previous css to no longer apply, but it does.

I've tried the JavaScript above to set the checked value to `false`.

When I console.log:

```js
$("#partner-1").prop("checked")
```

or

```js
document.getElementById("partner-1").checked
```

I get `false`.

If I console.log:

```js
$("#partner-1:checked").length
```

I get `1`.  I'm expecting `0` and figuring this is where the css is evaluating to `true` for that rule.

Comment: Does "partner-1" appear as the id of more than one `<input>` element? If so, that is not valid markup.

Comment: Also what does the `:before` CSS rule(s) look like for that "slider" element other than the one with the `:checked` selector?

Comment: No, partner-1 only appears once on the page.  I've updated the post with the full slider css.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot.  I checked `$("#partner-1").length` and only got 1 but when I looked closer there were 2 instances of it.

Comment: It's kind-of interesting that jQuery found both via its strange, old, and complicated selector resolution code, but that's kind-of why it's good to avoid duplicate id values: you never know what weird thing will happen.